# How to delay Vertica node shutdown when k-safety assessment fails?

Tags: vertica

We're using a 3 nodes Vertica cluster. 
The network connection between the nodes sometimes fails for a short amount of time (ex : 10 seconds).

When this happens, all nodes quickly shut down as soon as they detect that other nodes are unreachable (because k-safety cannot be satisfied). For example, the following sequence is recorded in the vertica log by the node0003 :

```
00:04:30.633 node v_feedback_node0001 left the cluster
...
00:04:30.670 Node left cluster, reassessing k-safety...
...
00:04:32.389 node v_feedback_node0002 left the cluster
...
00:04:32.414 Changing node v_feedback_node0003 startup state from UP to UNSAFE
...
00:04:33.425 Shutting down this node
...
00:04:38.547 node v_feedback_node0003 left the cluster
```

Is it possible to configure a delay after which each node will try to reconnect to others before giving up and shutting down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an answer from a Vertica employee on the [Vertica forum](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/239006/how-to-delay-vertica-node-shutdown-when-k-safety-assessment-fails).

> This [reconnection delay] time is hard coded to 8 seconds.
>
> I think time is better spent making the network more reliable. 30 sec
>   of network failure is a lot (i mean really, really large, typically
>   network rtt is in the microseconds). even if you kept vertica up by
>   delaying k-safe assessment, nothing really can connect to the
>   database, or most likely all db connections may reset.